# xml to DataFrame in scala

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, rdd

Currently in my scala-project I use kafka to recive xml data with spark-streaming. I'm doing it in simple way:

```
KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc,kafkaparams,topics)
val lines = inputstream.map(_._2)
lines.foreachRDD(rdd => {
   rdd.foreach(record => {
   println(record)}
   )}    
)
```

After that I have to convert my string to DataFrame. For that I'am using export to .xml and import with sqlcontext.read.load("pathtofile") and everything works fine.

The question: Is it possible to convert single-line xml-string to DataFrame directly from kafka-rdd and how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

With usage of [xml loader](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml) you can achieve your goal like:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
    .option("rowTag", "<your tag>")
    .load("<path to your xml>")
```

Comment: Yes, I've already use this way to import existing xml from file, and, as I've mentioned, it works great. But my question how create df directly from rdd, that i have on step of receiving xml from kafka :)